# The active plugin for vaadin to create ui in XML

Tags: vaadin

I am basically from vaadin and i tried vaadin and it looks promising and i found some plugins 
clara,XMLUI etc

which is the best one or which is similar to zkoss and  active or which is the best design patterns in vaadin ?

Answer (score 0):

[Clara](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/clara) is a little bit more mature. I would suggest to give it a try.

Anyway, there are a lot of limitations behind any XML-based UI generation tool. So please follow [PoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept) approach to make sure your task can be solved with any of these addons.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very old but maybe the following webinar concerning Clara can help others: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFS5gkq2AzQ